# How can get Buffer from already saved PDF in NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, pdf, buffer, backblaze

I have to upload the pdf file to Backblaze bucket.
which accepts Buffer only.
PDF file is already stored in one of my directory.
i can access that pdf through fs.

while uploading i have to give buffer.
Which is the best way to get buffer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found simple way without using Buffer..
I can pass the file path to readFileSync() in fs

Example
`const buff =  fs.readFileSync("pdfs/abcd.pdf")`

Comment: Glad you figured it out! Could you 'accept' your answer so it shows the nice green checkmark and it's more clear that it's been answered correctly?

Comment: Yes done
Accepted it

Comment: Hey! I used this today! :) let me add an upvote